# Unable to run database query when Session Object is not static?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

Here is my test class:

```
public class test {


public static void main(String args[])
{
    database_connection db=new database_connection();
    java.util.List li=db.select("select name from sign_up where   u_id='ABCD79'");
    java.util.Iterator it=li.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        Object oo=it.next();
        System.out.println("The result is "+oo.toString());
    }
}
```

}

Here is my database connection file:

```
public class database_connection
{
public static SessionFactory sessionfactory;
public  Session Listsession ;
public Query query;
public List list;

public static void open_connection()
{
try
{
database_connection   db=new database_connection();
sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
db.Listsession = sessionfactory.openSession();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 System.out.print("problem to open connection with database"+e);
 }
 }   

public  List select(String qry)
{ 
 try
    {

    open_connection();   
    Listsession.beginTransaction();
    query =Listsession.createQuery(qry);
    list=query.list();
    Listsession.getTransaction().commit();
    Listsession.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

        Listsession.getTransaction().rollback();
        System.out.print("problem to select"+e);
    }
 return list;
 }
 }
```

In this case test returns null pointer exception but when i replace this line `public  Session Listsession ;` with `public static Session Listsession ;` I am getting `name` from database.I don't know why this is happening because i want every user to have a different session object and i can't make session object static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with this code

```
try
{
database_connection   db=new database_connection();
sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
db.Listsession = sessionfactory.openSession();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 System.out.print("problem to open connection with database"+e);
}
}
```

What you are doing is creating a new object of
database_connection class here and to Listsession of that object you are getting the session. So for test class which creates the object of database_connection actually has no session instance.

Try following code instead of above, it should solve the problem.

```
try
{
sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Listsession = sessionfactory.openSession();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 System.out.print("problem to open connection with database"+e);
}
}
```

Comment: How can i access a non static variable Listsession directly.

Comment: Remove static from open_connection().

Comment: Accepting the answer would really help.

Comment: Just one more question that i am opening and closing connection at start and end of method is it okay or should i just open session when user logins.

Comment: Sorry open connection not opensession

Comment: I suggest you continue the same way you are doing it in your code.